# Open Jupyter Notebook from a Drive Other than C Drive

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a machine learning project in drive D. It contains python notebook files. But when I launch jupyter notebook through command prompt, it only shows directories inside drive C. How can I navigate to a drive other than C drive without changing jupyter notebook startup path?. I'm using windows 10 operating system. All the solutions I found, trying to change notebook startup path.

Comment: Move yourself to D drive before launching jupyter notebook: Open command prompt, type `D:`, then `jupyter notebook`. Or do you mean you want to access both drives at the same time?

Comment: I can only launch notebook from Jupyter Notebook desktop app by searching from start. When I try on command prompt, it doesn't recognize jupyter command.

Comment: If you installed Jupyter via Anaconda, use `jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=D:/` in **Anaconda prompt** instead of Command prompt.

Comment: What if we need to access both drives?

Answer (score 192, accepted):

You can launch it from any drive/location you want with the `--notebook-dir` option.

For example:

```sh
jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=D:/
```

Comment: Perfect. Just one thing, I had to give --notebook-dir=D: without the forward slash.

Comment: for windows no need for '/' before drive name:
`jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=D:`

Comment: note that this needs to be issued in the **Anaconda prompt** not the windows powershell

Comment: @ChenmingZhang It does work in a Windows command prompt

Comment: Fantastic! This helped me run `jupyter lab --notebook-dir=D:` and launch in the drive I needed.

Answer (score 42):

Follow these steps:

1. Open Anaconda Prompt
2. Insert this command,
   `jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=NameOfTheDrive:`.

As Example for Drive D, `jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=D:`

Answer (score 24):

To permanently change the default directory of Jupyter do the following:

- Look for the Shortcut to open Jupyter notebook.
- Right Click on the Shortcut
- Go to Properties.
- Look for ....jupyter-notebook-script.py "%USERPROFILE%/"
- Change %USERPROFILE%/ to the folder you wish.
- Restart Jupyter notebook.

Comment: Example of __Change "%USERPROFILE%/" to the folder you wish__. For example: you can put "F:/" instead of  "%USERPROFILE%/", This would open your Jupyter root screen in F drive and then you can proceed to create the notebook in any folder(or new folder) you want in that drive.

Answer (score 10):

Open the Anaconda Prompt

type the following:

```sh
jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=D:\
```

This is what worked for me in windows.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using **JupyterLab**, just type in your desired terminal;

```
jupyter lab --notebook-dir=D:/
```

It will create a new port to access D: drive in JupyterLab

Answer (score 7):

Okay, this question seems to have already been addresses, but I'd like to add quick step launch solution for this case. I created a batch file (windows .bat file) with the following script and saved it on my desktop. I just double click it to launch the files in the respective drive.

```
@echo ON
title Launch Jupyter notebooks from Drive D
jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=D:
@echo OFF
```

Copy paste this code in a text file and save it as a *.bat file on your Desktop. Just fire it up every time you want to launch Jupyter.

You can create various versions of this file for each drive as required and keep them handy.

Answer (score 6):

Another good option is from your terminal go to the disk you want to start jupyter by example :

```
cd D:
```

And then launch jupyter notebook

```
jupyter notebook
```

Comment: This did not seem to work with me.

Answer (score 3):

1. Open Jupyter notebook as usual
2. Click on New\Terminal
3. Type the code below in terminal, where you want to point to F drive

   ```
   jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=F:/
   ```
4. Jupter notebook new session url will open in your default internet explorer

Answer (score 3):

you can directly access by following command:

`jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=D:/`

Alternate method is go to Anaconda Prompt or Anaconda Termial
then Access D drive and launch the jupyter notebook

```
D:
jupyter notebook
```

Answer (score 2):

*To change just one time :
user following code in your Anaconda prompt .
jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=E:

*To permanently change the default directory of Jupyter do the following:
Right click on Jupyter notebook icon.
Go to Properties.
In shortcut tab->target you will find something like this -> jupyter-notebook-script.py "%USERPROFILE%/"
Change %USERPROFILE%/ to the folder you want to start from eg : jupyter-notebook-script.py "E:\folder_path".
Restart Jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to create a batch file which allows me to execute `jupyter` at the current directory.

1. Create a batch file `jupy.bat` with the following content:

```sh
   jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=%1
```

2. Save the jupy.bat in some folder, let say in `d:\scripts`
3. Append `d:\scripts` in PATH environment variable. So that i can call `jupy` just everywhere.
4. From now on, i can go to the folder where i store my notebooks, and execute the command:

```sh
    jupy .
```

Answer (score 1):

This is to open Jupiter lab from E Drive

Open Anaconda Prompt
Type the code below in terminal, where you want to point to E drive

```
jupyter lab --notebook-dir=E:/
```

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.

Comment: This opens the lab in my browser. But I want to keep using my desktop app. How can I change the directory for a desktop app?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Anaconda Navigator, do the following steps.

Open command prompt (CMD.exe Prompt)

Type "D:" and press enter.

Now type "Jupyter Notebook" in the next line and press enter.

Wait for few seconds, you will be automatically redirected to Jupyter notebook.

Comment: Jupyter : The term 'Jupyter' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. WINDOWS 10

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers worked for me on Windows 11. This did the trick on Anaconda Prompt:

```
(base) C:\>cd /d d:
(base) D:\>jupyter notebook
```

Answer (score 0):

My repositories are in the drive R.

I am running Jupyter on Windows 10 in the Ubuntu 18.04, so the drive R is at /mnt/r.

```
$ nano ~/.bashrc  
alias notebook="jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=/mnt/r" 
$ source ~/.bashrc  
$ notebook
```

It does not open the browser automatically, so I have to copy the URL manually.
It may ask you to enter the token which you can get by executing:

```
$ jupyter notebook list
```

Answer (score 0):

The most easiest solution in my opinion

- Open Notepad
- Paste the command "jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1.0e10"
- Save the notepad file with an extension of ".bat" instead of ".txt"
- Paste the file in which directory you want to initialize your jupyter
- Double click and open the ".bat" file
- Jupyter opens with desired directory as base
- This way you control the jupyter root directory as and when required and don't
  really have to perform any manual settings

Hope this helps

".bat" file created on Desktop

[image]

".bat" file double clicked and executed

[image]

jupyter opens with Desktop as the intended base directory

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you need to start notebook from drive D;

```
jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=D:
```

works for me in windows.

Comment: This adds nothing new compared to [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55369484/3966456)