# Unable to start kernel for jupyter notebooks in a specific directory

Tags: directory, jupyter-notebook, kernel

No problem in other directories. Is there an environmental variable or something else I need to erase?
Deleted cache file...

**OK, I think I need be much clearer here.**

First software:

- MacOS Catalina 10.15.6
- jupyter notebook 6.0.3
- Python 3.8.3
- IPython 7.16.1

**jupyter notebook is installed and runs fine.**

jupyter notebook runs just fine in any user directory on the computer ***except exactly one***.

There is nothing obvious in this directory that shouldn't be there. An 'ls -al' shows nothing but some .py files.

I can create a jupyter notebook in this directory, but the kernel crashes and won't restart. I can rename the directory, rename the jupyter notebook, but the behavior persists beyond everything I have been able to reset including a cold computer restart. It is reproducible and happens every time.

This behavior is not seen in any other directory.

**My question:** are there environmental variables or caches stored not visibly in the directory (obviously) that are responsible for this incredibly annoying behavior and how can I reset them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open Jupyter Notebook from a Drive Other than C Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55078484/open-jupyter-notebook-from-a-drive-other-than-c-drive)

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved: jupyter notebooks apparently uses some reserved names for local directory .py files when starting up the notebook. So far I've found that "string.py" and "decorator.py" cannot be in the startup directory unless they contain the expected data (looks like it needs to be related to some template info)

Comment: Thanks lot! i'd been struggling with this for hours. Another reserved name you can add to that list (as for my case) is a basic `code.py`

Answer (score 0):

To start-up a kernel

You first activate your virtual environment:

For instance: `conda activate vision`

Second, you type `jupyter notebook`

as stated [here](https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/running.html)