# Read Files from Google Drive in JupyterLab

Tags: google-drive-api, jupyter-lab

I have installed the jupyter lab extension to connect to google drive.
I can create and open files in the drive from the JupyterLab UI.
But I can't find a way to read files located in the drive in the notebook.
For example I would want to be able to run in my notebook the following:

```py
df = pd.read_csv("Gdrive/MyDrive/somefileinthedrive.csv")
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 5):

You could open jupyterlab directly in the Google Drive directory like this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69077943/13129641

I use to open jupyterlab from anaconda prompt with:

```
python -m jupyterlab --notebook-dir=G:/
```

Note: You can change `G:/` to another directory, if you desire.