# I'm having error opening up a file using scanpy in jupyter notebook. It says permission denied

Tags: jupyter-notebook

[Thats the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvMn4.png)

tried using double slashes, still not resolved
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[17], line 1
----> 1 sc.read_csv('G:\scanpy data\extracted\GSM5226574_C51ctr_raw_counts.csv').T

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\anndata_io\read.py:54, in read_csv(filename, delimiter, first_column_names, dtype)
30 def read_csv(
31     filename: Union[PathLike, Iterator[str]],
32     delimiter: Optional[str] = ",",
33     first_column_names: Optional[bool] = None,
34     dtype: str = "float32",
35 ) -> AnnData:
36     """
37     Read `.csv` file.
38
(...)
52         Numpy data type.
53     """
---> 54     return read_text(filename, delimiter, first_column_names, dtype)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\anndata_io\read.py:358, in read_text(filename, delimiter, first_column_names, dtype)
356         return _read_text(f, delimiter, first_column_names, dtype)
357 else:
--> 358     with filename.open() as f:
359         return _read_text(f, delimiter, first_column_names, dtype)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\pathlib.py:1117, in Path.open(self, mode, buffering, encoding, errors, newline)
1115 if "b" not in mode:
1116     encoding = io.text_encoding(encoding)
-> 1117 return self._accessor.open(self, mode, buffering, encoding, errors,
1118                            newline)

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'G:\scanpy data\extracted\GSM5226574_C51ctr_raw_counts.csv'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PermissionError: \[Errno 13\] in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207450/permissionerror-errno-13-in-python)

Comment: Jupyter maybe cannot access that drive. It looks like your Jupyter is running elsewhere based on `~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\anndata_io\read.py`. And so move the file to some place Jupyter can access and then try with that new path. See [answers to 'Open Jupyter Notebook from a Drive Other than C Drive'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55078484/8508004).